# Pixel search in defined area

Tags: autoit, bluestacks

I want to pixel search a defined area. Application is Bluestacks App Player:

[image]

Blue rectangle is BlueStacks (its position may change). I get the position using `ControlGetPos()`. I only want to pixel search in red rectangle inside the app. Position of red rectangle is **307,628,355,675** based on window info with windows coordinate mode. But It's not working. Here's my code :

```
HotKeySet("{F2}", "mulai")
HotKeySet("{F3}", "berhenti")

Global $lokasi[2]
Global $warna
Global $penghitung
Global $nyala
Global $title = "BlueStacks App Player"
Global $hwnd = WinGetHandle($title)
Global $BSpos

Func berhenti()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>berhenti

Func getPos()
    $aPos = ControlGetPos($title, "", "[CLASS:BlueStacksApp; INSTANCE:1]")
    $tPoint = DllStructCreate("int X;int Y")
    DllStructSetData($tPoint, "X", $aPos[0])
    DllStructSetData($tPoint, "Y", $aPos[1])
    _WinAPI_ClientToScreen(WinGetHandle(WinGetTitle($title)), $tPoint)

    $BSpos[0] = DllStructGetData($tPoint, "X")
    $BSpos[1] = DllStructGetData($tPoint, "Y")
EndFunc   ;==>getPos

Func mulai()
    $nyala = 1
    While $nyala = 1
        $pos = WinGetPos($hwnd)

        WinActivate($hwnd)
        $lokasi = PixelSearch($BSpos[0] , $BSpos[1], $BSpos[0] + $BSpos[2], $BSpos[1] + $BSpos[3], 0x0185B3)
        MouseMove($lokasi[0], $lokasi[1], 0)
        Sleep(200)
        If @error Then
            $penghitung = $penghitung + 1
        EndIf
        If $penghitung > 5 Then
            $nyala = 0
        EndIf
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>mulai

While 1
    Sleep(200)
WEnd
```

Comment: How did you get the search color? I suggest using printscreen then insert it in photoshop and get the color with color tool. If you save the image bedore inspecting , make sure you save it as bmp

Comment: Please also reformat your code to a) contain all relevant include statements and b) to contain readable English variable names or at least comments pointing out their content/meaning. Also, you might want to use a flavor of `ImageSearch` to look for that button.

Comment: Do move your mouse around the four corners of your red rectangles coordinates to verify them. Put a sleep in between your motions and go to the left upper und the right lower corner and see whether you need to change the way, your PixelCoordinates are being adressed. There are some different ways, it's called PixelCoordMode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's nothing wrong with the imagesearch library, the problem is I running windows 10 using x64bit. So compiling it using x64 compiler (while it really suggest to use x86 compiler) with administrator previllige solved the problem.